# Same Query-method diffrent results; Can springboot or hibernate block a query if object is (incompletely) loaded in memory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I hope I can make myself clear and get to the core of the problem. So I have an app where I use Spring-boot and hibernate. I use JPA-repository interfaces for DAO.
I have an object called NameSection which is held by 7 diffrent objects.
The NameSection has 3 lists of diffrent name-objects (latin name, common name, swedish name).
When I call my service.getNameSection(30); for instance, I get diffrent results depending on where I call it. If I call it from my controller where I have an incomplete copy of the namesection it doesn't seem to want to make a query to my database even though I call my service and the getNameSection(nameSectionId); (which in turn is calling my JPA-Repositories).

Is it possible that Spring boot or Hibernate stops the query to my database because it has what it thinks is a complete NameSection in it's memory?

The method that I'm struggeling with is called when I in a form submit an object (lets say Plant-object) and want to move on to a related NameSection form.

When I submit my Plant-form I get the plant injected to my method as an modelAttribute.
In this method I get the NameSection-id and make the call service.getNameSection(nameSectionId); and it doesn't give me the complete name section. In the plant-form I do refer to the namesection so in my CommonName-list (in NameSection) I have one loaded CommonName. But there are more to collect which is why I call my service.

I kind of boiled it down to this:
If I submit Plant-form which holds NameSection.id=30 and I call service.getNameSection(30); I will get the nameSection with just the one CommonName.

If I submit another Plant-form which holds another NameSection, but I hardcoded service.getNameSection(30); and logged it anyway just as a test I do get the complete NameSection (30) and fully loaded list.

What is even more frustrating is that the NameSection works as I want for the object type Fish which also holds a NameSection. Both methods follow the exact same flow. In the method below, just replace every "plant" with "fish" and it's the same.

My suspicion is that spring or hibernate or something takes a shortcut. I tried nulling the Plant and the NameSection before calling service.getNameSection(id); as well but it just wont load a complete nameSection if I already have an incomplete copy even if it's nulled. At least this is how it seems to me. I've been stuck for days.

Calling service.getPlant(plantId); will also load the complete NameSection, but this doesn't work either in this specific method. Works fine in my editPlant-method in the same Controller-class for instance.

So, this is the method:

```
// Process Plant form
@RequestMapping("/processPlantForm")
public String savePlantForm(Model model,
@RequestParam("saveButt") String saveButt,
// plant holds an incomplete namesection at this point
@Valid @ModelAttribute("plant") Plant plant, 
BindingResult theBindingResult){

...snipped validation...


plantService.savePlant(plant);

if (saveButt.equals("Edit NameSection")) {

   // Here is the problem section!!

NameSection nameSec = 
    plantService.getNameSection(plant.getNameSection().getId());
System.out.println("common names size: " + nameSec.getCommonNames().size());

   // Hardcoded test phrase         
   NameSection secNameSec = plantService.getNameSection(30);       
   System.out.println("common names size: " + secNameSec.getCommonNames().size());

model.addAttribute("plant", plant);
model.addAttribute("nameSectionForm", new NameSectionForm(nameSec));
model.addAttribute("inflateNameSection", true);
    return "form/create-plant";
}

else {      
    return "redirect:/listPlant";
}
}
```

So, going in to this method with the plant that holds the NameSection with id 30, it will in both "getNameSection(*id*)"-calls load the NameSection (id=30) with just one CommonName (which matches the incomplete NameSection from modelAttribute).

Going in tho this method with any other plant which does NOT hold NameSection (id=30) it will load a complete NameSection (id=30) with all related CommonNames in my "Hardcoded test phrase".

In both cases I will get all swedish names and all latin names related to the NameSection, probably  because they are both empty Lists in the incomplete NameSection from the ModelAttribute.

So, I expected plantService.getNameSection(nameSectionId); to give the same result always, for the same nameSectionId ofc. But it seems that some "smart short-cut" makes it skip a few steps if pieces are available in memory and that it in this case makes false assumptions, or is it just me?

I could perhaps create a special query to ask for the missing CommonNames, but there must be a neater way. And what's killing me is that it does work 1 out of the 7 diffrent objects that holds the namesection. Of course there should be some diffrence between them, but I just can't find it. The only diffrence I found was that I initially had "Model model" after "BindingResult theBindingResult" in the method injection. I moved it as to match the working method for fishes but it didn't make any diffrence.

I also tried adding a call to getCommonNames().size() in my service.getNameSection(id)-method to "collect Lazy-list" but it made no diffrence.

Any Pro's who got some idea what's up?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to create more of a wall of text than I did, but I figured someone will want to see the working fish-method mentioned.

```
    @RequestMapping("/processFishForm")
    public String processFishForm(Model model,
                            @RequestParam("saveButt") String saveButt,
                            @Valid @ModelAttribute("fish") Fish fish,           
                            BindingResult theBindingResult) {
    
    // this is the snipped validation from plant-method example above
    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(theBindingResult.getAllErrors());
        return "form/create-fish";
    }
    
    fishService.saveFish(fish);
    
    if (saveButt.equals("Edit NameSection")) {
        NameSection nameSec = fishService.getNameSection(fish.getNameSection().getId());

        model.addAttribute("inflateNameSection", true);
        model.addAttribute("fish", fish);
        model.addAttribute("nameSectionForm", new NameSectionForm(nameSec););
        return "form/create-fish";
    } 
    else {
        return "redirect:/listFish";
    }
}
```

Both the FishService and PlantService have the exact same getNameSection(id)-method and they are 100% interchangeable according to my tests.

***Update***
So I created a new DAO (JpaRepository-interface) for CommonNames (since I had none) and created the custom method:

```
List<CommonName> findByNameSection(NameSection nameSection);
```

Then in the service when I call for a NameSection the service will call that method aswell to make sure I get all the CommonNames. Now it works as I want it to. Except that I probably make an unnecessary query to the database to fix something else.

***Update 2:*** I have become a bit wiser and in case somebody stumbles in with similar questions, what I was needing/looking for was a refresh method for my object. Since I use JpaRepository I googled and found the simplest way to implement a refresh-method. It was a little too complicated for me to go trough when probably noone cares, but I used this example which works fine. https://www.javabullets.com/add-entitymanager-refresh-spring-data-repositories/